# Aggregate timestamp values by the according day in a given time zone

Tags: postgresql, datetime, timezone, timestamp

`published` is `timestamp with time zone` stored as UTC.
`gps_coordinates` is `geography(Point,4326)`.

```
SELECT
    ST_MakeLine(pp.Gps_Coordinates::geometry ORDER BY pp.Published) As DailyRoute,
    pp.Published::date As DayOf
FROM xxxx As pp
WHERE pp.Id = 'xxxxxxxx'
GROUP BY DayOf
```

I am trying to get all of the data for the Id by day but in the timezone of the person who requested it, so if in CST everything that happened between 00:00:00 CST and 23:59:59 CST, or if in EST everything that happened between 00:00:00 EST and 23:59:59 EST.

What is the best way to rework this query to get the data using this information?

When I tried:

```
SELECT
    ST_MakeLine(pp.Gps_Coordinates::geometry ORDER BY pp.Published) As DailyRoute,
    pp.Published::date AT TIME ZONE 'CST'  As DayOf
FROM xxxx As pp
WHERE pp.Id = 'xxxxxxxx'
GROUP BY DayOf
```

The dayof results in `2018-11-25 18:00:00`, this is not what I want.  I want to group by everything during the day based on the time of day in the Local Time Zone.

Comment: The name of the Postgres data type is `timestamp with time zone`. I took the liberty and replaced `DateTime With TimeZone` accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to group by everything during the day based on the time of day in the Local Time Zone.

If by "local time zone" you mean the user-provided 'CST', then use:

```
(pp.Published AT TIME ZONE 'CST')::date AS DayOf
```

Instead of

<strike>`pp.Published::date AT TIME ZONE 'CST'  As DayOf`</strike>

If you cast to `date` first, you get the date as defined by the `timezone` setting of the current session (`show timezone;`). The following `AT TIME ZONE` construct first coerces the given `date` value to a [`timestamptz` (`timestamp with time zone`)](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) representing `00:00` of the given date for the current `timezone` setting, before computing the respective `timestamp without time zone` for the given time zone ('CST') - *not* what you want.

Related:

- [Ignoring time zones altogether in Rails and PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571392/ignoring-time-zones-altogether-in-rails-and-postgresql/9576170#9576170)